# the definition of the maximum value of a continuous function is impredicative?

Tags: logic

[Mathematical Thought From Ancient to Modern Times: Volume 3, P1199](https://books.google.ae/books?id=8YaBuGcmLb0C&pg=PA1199&lpg=PA1199&dq=Another%20example%20of%20an%20impredicative%20definition%20is%20the%20definition%20of%20the%20maximum%20value%20of%20a%20continuous%20function%20defined%20over%20a%20closed%20interval%20as%20the%20largest%20value%20that%20the%20function%20takes%20on%20in%20this%20interval.&source=bl&ots=EMLgOVf_vM&sig=-P_wanZdIhx9frE--KKopBdjKtc&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Another%20example%20of%20an%20impredicative%20definition%20is%20the%20definition%20of%20the%20maximum%20value%20of%20a%20continuous%20function%20defined%20over%20a%20closed%20interval%20as%20the%20largest%20value%20that%20the%20function%20takes%20on%20in%20this%20interval.&f=false) says

> Another example of an impredicative definition is the definition of
> the maximum value of a continuous function defined over a closed
> interval as the largest value that the function takes on in this
> interval.

I cannot understand why the definition is impredicative, any one can give a clear explanation ?

Comment: See [Impredicativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impredicativity): "Roughly speaking, a definition is impredicative if it invokes (mentions or quantifies over) the set being defined, or (more commonly) another set that contains the thing being defined." In the above case, we have that the largest value is one of the values that the function takes.

Comment: The "maximum" value is defined as the "largest" value. So the "maximum" value is defined as the "maximal" value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the definition is stated that way, we are essentially making a set $V$: the set of values that the function takes on the interval. Then we define the maximum value, $m$, as the largest value of $V$. But $m$ is already an element of $V$, which is why this can be seen as impredicative.

There are other definitions of the maximum value of a continuous function that are not impredicative. For example, $m$ is the maximum if and only if there is no rational $q$ in the interval so that $f(q) > m$, and for every positive rational $r$ there is a rational $q$ in the interval with $f(q) > m-r$.   If we already have the rational numbers and the function $f$, then this definition implicitly characterizes $m$ - even if $m$ is not rational - but only quantifying over sets that we already have.